# Black or Corrupt UI Artifacts Under Wine

Tags: wine, visual-artifacts

This is something that's been bugging me for quite some time.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the issue as seen in **Microsoft Office Word 2007**.

[image: Issue in Word 2007]

While it doesn't get in the way when it's like this, I've had to uninstall other apps as the black artefacts affected usability.

Here is the same issue in **Excel 2007**.

[image]

**Setup**
I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 10.10, with an Intel 945 chipset.

Comment: I recently switched machines to a Lenovo Thinkpad X201 and have the same problem. I have the same problem using Crossover and their support team pointed to the same driver bug.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from [Word 2007's AppDB page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12811) this looks more to be a graphics driver bug

> xf86-video-intel 2.12.0 and newer
>
> GUI controls are painted black: http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30157   Downgrade to 2.11.0.

Reverting to an older driver is not really practical (it's possible but it's a very manual process). That bug report suggests a registry work-around. Either browse to the right location in `regedit` or save this as a `.reg` file and run it through `regedit`

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\X11 Driver]
"ClientSideWithRender"="N"
```

However, there is at least one person who says this makes things worse. But [that bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30157) is where you want to track the issue. Wine have washed their hands of it.

Comment: I can verify that registry key mod does eliminate the black artifacts in O2007; however, it introduces other issues. I lost the close,minimize,maximize buttons, but also the Office 2007 button... my reaction is that this fix is not usable.

Comment: Kendor is right, this registry hack doesn't work well at all for Office 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I have back-ported a fix for this bug for natty. Please can you install the xserver-xorg-video-intel from ppa:smorar/bugfixes and check if this resolves this issue for you.

If there is enough interest, I may try and push this through as a SRU for natty (11.04).